# Clean a Play framework build in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, playframework, intellij-idea

I had a spelling mistake in the `conf/routes` file which caused incorrectly named classes to be generated by Play Framework. Rebuilding project and even running `Invalidate Caches` does not solve the problem in IntelliJ.

The incorrect class files were re-generated when I manually run `play clean` from the command line.

Is there an equivalent of `Build Clean` for Play Framework projects in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either cd to the project and run **play clean compile**

or

create a run configuration to make it directly from IDEA:
[image]

Comment: if you use activator,you can change program to activator command

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is is play 2.x you can run the command:

```
cd <project-dir>

../play clean-all
```