# Play 2.2 Framework with IntelliJ IDEA 12

Tags: java, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to get Play 2.2 to run in IntelliJ IDEA but I'm having a few problems. It looks like the Play 2 Framework plugin doesn't work with Play 2.2.

Setting up a project using the `play` console and creating an IntelliJ project using the `idea` command seems to work. However, I'm not sure how I can run/debug the Play app from within the IDE without starting it externally via the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For running you should create run config: [Clean a Play framework build in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878098/clean-a-play-framework-build-in-intellij/18879694#18879694)

Shift + F9 starts debug.